# Continuous Streaming PCM data in C++?

Tags: c++, audio, audio-streaming, pcm

I have a stream of PCM audio captured from a cell phone, and I want to play it.

I am trying to find a lightweight method of playing this audio in C++.

I can already slap on a wave header and create a file that plays in any media player, but I want to play the file in real time as it streams in. I would like to avoid writing the file to disc just to read it again, and I also don't want to have pauses in the audio as I stop one file and start another.

I realize that OpenAL provides audio streaming functionality, but I was hoping for something simpler. I only need to play a single channel PCM stream.

Does anyone know of a lightweight, free(for commercial use) library or windows API that can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [waveOut](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=4422&lngWId=3) API in Windows

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [patent has expired](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/4366439.html), so there should be no legal complications.  The beauty of a patent is that it makes the algorithm public.

Comment: However, if I used FMOD to play the file, I would have to pay because the software is still under copyright.

Answer (score 0):

Playing a single PCM stream is not THAT simple, alas.  Its not that hard. I've not used OpenAL but under standard windows audio, XAudio2 or DirectSound its easy to use a double buffered.  Play buffer 1 while filling buffer 2 from the stream.  Then play buffer2 while filling buffer1 and so on.